# Waterproofing covered porch floor with basement below

Tags: flooring, waterproofing, porch, flashing

I have a covered entryway that is exposed on one side, with an unfinished basement below. The original flooring was 2x6's which have been removed. My plan is to replace them with a stone mosaic. The floor currently consists of an asphalt membrane, aluminum flashing, and plywood on top of joists.

Below are some photos of what I am working with.

- The asphalt membrane has a series of holes from nailing down the
  2x6's which I have filled with caulking, however, it looks aged and I
  don't trust its waterproofing.
- The ledger OSB (which will be removed/replaced) was originally
  wrapped in asphalt paper.

My thought is to remove the existing asphalt membrane, replace the ledger OSB with aluminum flashing, and install a modern adhesive membrane like ice and water shield on the top, flowing over the front.

I would love some more experienced opinions since I am just a DIYer and this is my first experience with something like this.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: if you plan to install tiles, you need a backer board under them

Comment: @asinine No tiles, the mosaic will use the same pavers used to construct the front steps